# How to check a wxString with regular expressions like this

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxstring

I want to check user input a wxString just like this:

```
substring1, substring2, substring3, substringn
```

It means just subtring of alpha and comma between. How to do that, i am new, thanks for your help,.

Comment: Why do you think you need regular expressions for this? Why doesn't `wxString::find(", ")` cut it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following two classes:

[`wxSplit`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__string.html#ga530ba2b0b90c59bc3d98c0eaf6f7a912)

This can be used to create an array of wxString (`wxArrayString`) based on a separator character. So for example, the following code:

`wxSplit ("substring1, substring2, substring3, substringn", ',');`

would result in an wxArrayString containing:

```
substring1
 substring2
 substring3
 substringn
```

Note, the space before the later substrings. This is because `wxSplit` can only take a single char.

[`wxStringTokenizer`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string_tokenizer.html)

This is slightly more complex, and powerful. Adapting the example from the documentation:

```
wxStringTokenizer tokenizer("substring1, substring2, substring3, substringn", ",");
while ( tokenizer.HasMoreTokens() )
{
    wxString token = tokenizer.GetNextToken();
    wxPuts (token.Trim(false));
}
```

Would solve the leading space problem.

Comment: Adding link only answers is not encouraged. Could you summarize the main points on why using these 2 classes answers the question?

Comment: To be honest, the question is pretty vague. However, I have expanded the answer to provide a more complete explanation of what the 2 classes do.